# Setting default value in XAML Multibinding StringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I am new to XAML and I have to use it to modify the UI of a frontend system. The fields are fixed and I cannot modify them, therefore I need a creative solution to my problem that frankly, I don't have the skill to figure out despite my best efforts.

The UI is for displaying attributes of videogames in a database. Specifically, I'm interested in the part of the UI that currently allows for displaying an image of the video game's controller (different games use different controllers).

As is, the UI only allows for displaying a controller for every videogame belonging to a platform as demonstrated with the below code:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="PlatformControlPanel" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <TextBlock.Text>
         <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/Custom/Images/Controls/{0}/{0}.png">
             <Binding Path="SelectedGame.Platform" />
         </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
<Image Source="{Binding Text, ElementName=PlatformControlPanel}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

In the example above, the controller image is stored in the following directory format: /Themes/Custom/Images/Controls/"Platform Name"/"Platform Name".png

And this works super well but the problem is that a given platform can have more than one controller type such as joystick controllers or GamePad controllers.

So what I want to do is change the code so that it displays a default controller for a given platform but display a different controller for specific games that use a different controller type.

To do this, because I cannot set new fields in the database, I modified the code to display a controller based on the name of the game:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="PlatformControlPanel" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <TextBlock.Text>
         <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/Custom/Images/Controls/{1}/{0}.png">
              <Binding Path="SelectedGame.Title" />
              <Binding Path="SelectedGame.Platform" />
         </MultiBinding>
     </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
<Image Source="{Binding Text, ElementName=PlatformControlPanel}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

At this point, the UI looks to /Themes/Custom/Images/Controls/"Platform Name"/"Game Title".png

The problem is, the UI is only showing an image if "Game Title".png exists. Otherwise, it shows nothing.

I don't know how to set a default value so that if "Platform Name"/"Game Title".png doesn't exist, the UI will fallback on "Platform Name"/"Platform Name".png.

Can someone help me?

**Edit:**
Xaml update (unrelated code omitted, no errors reported when building):

```
<UserControl xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:BigBoxTheme.Views.Converters"

<!--Main Content Row-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <converter:MultiValueConverter x:Key="MultiValueConverter"/>
            </Grid.Resources>

<Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="selectedExample"/>
                            <Binding Path="ValidationTest"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace BigBoxTheme.Views.Converters
{
class MultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        BitmapImage result = null;
        //process the variables passed in
        Uri SourceUri = new Uri($"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/Custom/Images/Controls/{values[1]}/{values[0]}.png", UriKind.Absolute);//use either string format or whatever you like to create a valid Uri
        if (File.Exists(SourceUri.AbsolutePath))
        {
            //we have found the image
            //no need to do anything just let it run through
        }
        else
        {
            //use the default
            SourceUri = new Uri($"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/Custom/Images/Controls/{values[1]}/{values[1]}.png", UriKind.Absolute);
        }
        return new BitmapImage(SourceUri);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Binding use `TargetNullValue` like so:

```
<Binding Path="SelectedGame.Title" TargetNullValue="Platform Name" />
```

**EDIT**
After our conversation in comments I would recommend you use a converter, to be more precise a `Multi Value Converter`. It would look like this:

```
class MultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        BitmapImage result = null;
        //process the variables passed in
        Uri SourceUri = new Uri($"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/Custom/Images/Controls/{values[1]}/{values[0]}.png", UriKind.Absolute);//use either string format or whatever you like to create a valid Uri
        if (File.Exists(SourceUri.AbsolutePath))
        {
            //we have found the image
            //no need to do anything just let it run through
        }
        else
        {
             //use the default
             SourceUri = new Uri($"pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Themes/Custom/Images/Controls/{values[1]}/{values[1]}.png", UriKind.Absolute);
        }
        return new BitmapImage(SourceUri);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

you would then use it like this:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
            <Binding Path="SelectedExample"/>
            <Binding Path="ValidationTest"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

**EDIT 2**
The converter is in its own file, say `MultiValueConverter.cs`, it would go where your views are, preferably in a Folder called `Converters`. Now in the xaml at the top you would include that converter like this:

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:SO_app.Converters"//clr-namespace is the namespace of your view followed by a dot to access the Converters folder
```

Now inside of your `Window` or `UserControl` resources tag like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converter:MultiValueConverter x:Key="MultiValueConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: That won't work because all games have titles and all games have platforms. There are no null values. I need a way to show a default image that only gets replaced when the multibinding is actually able to find an image based on the game title.

Comment: Ah, sorry. But you said "_The problem is, the UI is only showing an image if "Game Title".png exists._". So your game can have multiple images (multi platform game) but always there is at least one. So you want to have something that will detect the number of images available and then select default if there is more than one?

Comment: No. The directory structure is /Themes/Custom/Images/Platform Name. Inside that folder you have Platform Name.png (this would be the default image) and ONE image for EACH game that has a different controller type. Each of those images would be named the same as the game it is meant to be tied to. (for example, Super Mario.png, Kirby.png, etc). If a game does not have an image attributed to it, for example, I have a game called Pacman but there is no Pacman.png, I want the UI to show Platform Name.png instead.

Comment: So the nulls are at the HDD side, so when you navigate to PacMan game then you need to get the `Platform Name.png`. I would suggest use of a converter on the image and remove that text block.

Comment: Seeing as I am new to XAML, I have no idea how to make the C# code work. If I paste the code right into my xaml file it just crashes.

Comment: Almost there! I put everything in the right place and I get this: Cannot set MultiBinding because MultiValueConverter must be set

Comment: I put the cs file in a Converters folder in the Views folder. I had to remove the .Converters from the xmlns call in order to prevent errors. However, I get this error when I try to run my UI: Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:BigBoxTheme.Views}MultiValueConverter'

Comment: Show us how you declared it in your xaml?

Comment: The way I usually do it is create the .cs files first, build the solution and then use them in xaml, as sometimes designer can't cope with changes that are not built.

Comment: I redid everything from scrath, starting with the C# and the same problem occurs.

Comment: I'm finally getting somewhere! However, I need to get your code into public void OnSelectionChanged(FilterType filterType, string filterValue, IPlatform platform, IPlatformCategory category, IPlaylist playlist, IGame game){ CODE INSIDE HERE} and it isn't working. I'm getting errors i'm assuming because its a class inside a class.

Comment: From what I can see is that your converter class is not public that's why it can't create it. WPF will use relfection to access these classes so they need to be visible externally.